# .emacs.d folder equivalent for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, dotfiles

I want to know if there is any place where eclipse stores all my configurations so that only the config files can be ported across different machines(even different OS's)

If I spend my time customizing eclipse on my desktop , spending the same amount of time on every machine I work on is a no brainier. I was hoping eclipse stores its files in some directory in home directory(~/.emacs.d on linux/mac mainly, but use windows often as well) just like emacs does. With this I can easily put all my configurations under VCS and get exactly the same look and feel on every machine. I have done this for emacs actually and it works great. Like this https://github.com/anooprh/dotfiles/tree/master/emacs.d

I could not find anything like that for eclipse. The closest I could find was .eclipse folder in home directory

```
[user@localhost .eclipse]$ pwd
/home/user/.eclipse
[user@localhost .eclipse]$ ls
org.eclipse.platform_4.4.1_1473617060_linux_gtk_x86_64  org.eclipse.platform_4.4.1_1756587775_linux_gtk_x86_64
```

I dont know what these two directories. Inside that there were was a `configuration` directory as well, but could not find anything useful.

I want to know from people who have been using eclipse for some time as to how they manage to port their config files from one machine to another.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A lot of preferences are specific to a workspace and are stored in the workspace '.metadata/.plugins' folders.